# Any good "Ted Talk" sources for appreciating graph theory? (Vague/vogue question alert)

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to learn more about Graph Theory.  Just a "Ted Talk" caliber understanding.   I've played with Bridges of K. and 4-color map.  I get that stuff like Facebook or Netflix movie reviews may use some form of graph theory to represent people as vertices connected by edges in a graph.  I want to revisit some basic examples like traveling salesman, etc.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Links!

Comment: can you bump an old thread?